# How to get distance between left and right sides of the browser?

Tags: javascript

[image]

Is it possible to get current distance between left and right? Not full width.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté put it as an answer ;)

Comment: How is the distance between left and right not the width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.innerWidth) can be used to get the browser window viewport width, including scrollbars (if present and rendered).

There's also [`document.body.clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.clientWidth) which does not include scrollbar, margin, border, or padding - the latter 3 are irrelevant if you have `margin:0; padding:0;` and no border set to the `body`, which is the case when using a reset stylesheet. Otherwise you just have to compensate for these.

**Notes:**

- `clientWidth`, even though being supported by all major browsers (IE 5.5+, FF3+, Chrome, Opera, Safari), has never been defined by W3C so browser support may vary.
- `window.innerWidth` has a [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-window-innerwidth), but is not supported in IE < 9.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ePWtR/2/) comparing both.

---

**Edit:** `window.innerWidth` is not supported in IE<9, so using a mix of `innerWidth` and `clientWidth` (for older IE) is probably the best approach:

```
var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
```

Also, even though `clientWidth` is not standardized by the W3C, it is supported in all major browsers so many people find it reliable enough to use solely `clientWidth` instead of the W3C standard `innerWidth`.

If not including the scrollbar is important for your use-case then `clientWidth` can be used as the first/only option:

```
var viewportWidth = document.body.clientWidth; //no scrollbars included
```

Ensure that `body` has `margin:0` and `padding:0` in case you use the above.